# Wp8 how to add items in the stackpanel dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

I need help for item add in the stackpanel.
My item name is "kanal" its wp8 imagebutton item.
Its my codes

```
public mainpage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (var kanal in MainPage.kanalllarstatik)
    {
        mystackpanel.Children.Add(kanal);
    }           
}
```

I need add 130x130 pixel 3 button items per line like this:

[image: Its my app and button size is 130x130 pixel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackpanel only put one element per line so you need to put a horizontal stackpanel (in each line) and then add to it the three elements.

If you want a 130x130 control, you should use:

```
kanel.Height=130;
kanal.Width =130;
```

### Code example

#### Test Data

```
   List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            buttons.Add(new Button
            {
                Height = 130,
                Width = 130,
                Content = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = i.ToString()
                }
            });
        }
```

#### Algorithm

```
StackPanel horizontalStackPanel = new StackPanel
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            };

            foreach (Button button in buttons)
            {
                horizontalStackPanel.Children.Add(button);
                if (horizontalStackPanel.Children.Count == 3) //new line
                {
                   myStackPanel.Children.Add(horizontalStackPanel);
                    horizontalStackPanel = new StackPanel
                    {
                        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                    };
                }

            }
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(horizontalStackPanel);
```

**XAML**
`<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"></StackPanel>`

### Result

[image]

I hope that this can help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This buttons not 3 buttons I have lot of button, i am add dynamicaly "children.add" method. But i need 3 button per line like this picture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer good job :)